# Appending cor() values to vector while looping through files in R 3.1.1

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a function that goes through a directory of 332 files. Each file contains a data frame of air pollution values. Two columns are nitrate and sulfate.

As I go through each file, I need to determine if they meet a threshold criteria for complete cases. Basically, the code should omit any row with N/A or missing values. If they do meet the criteria, I will need to calculate a correlation between nitrate and sulfate using the `cor()` function.

This is my pseudocode:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){
setwd(paste("C:/...", directory, sep = "/"))

# Writing from here on works fine

correlations <- numeric()
files <- list.files(getwd(), full.names = TRUE)
for (i in 1:332) {
    read_file <- read.csv(file[i])
    complete_observation <- read_file[complete.cases(read_file), ]
    get number_complte using nrow
    if (number_complete >= threshold) {
        attach(complete_data)
        correlations <- c(correlations, cor(sulfate, nitrate))
        detach(complete_data)
    }
}
```

When I write this in manually (starting from the comment), it works fine and I get the results I am looking for, which is a correlation vector of a certain length.

However, when I try it by calling the function I created (starting from the beginning of the code), I get a NULL vector. I noticed that when I nested a return (correlation) after appending the cor data it returned a single value, which indicates that it is calculating a correlation value as it meets the criteria and is storing it at the end, but once it exits the loop it is re-initialized to 0.

This baffles me because it did not behave this way when it was typed in manually: this behavior only occurs when I run the function. There should be no difference in the behavior of the function between both cases. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible for you to upload the code you written? When you provide your code and sample data, you are likely to receive help from someone.

Comment: @jazzuro Thanks! Should I add it as an edit? I tried adding it as a comment, but I was not able to format it properly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my function to work the way I wanted to by placing a return statement after the second closing bracket, basically after each for loop iteration

```
corr <- function(...){    
correlation <- numeric()
  for(...){
  ...
  if (num_com >= threshold){
    correlation <- c(correlation, cor(x,y))
    correlation <- c(correlation, cor(data$nitrate, data$sulfate))
    }
  }
  return(correlation)
}
```